# Obtaining predicted probabilities from multinomial logistic regression using coefficients as input (not the model)

Tags: r, predict, multinomial

I wonder if R has a function that can compute the predicted probabilities from the multinomial logistic regression coefficients (not the model), assuming that we do not have the model and what we have are multinomial logistic coefficients only.

Comment: You can transform coefs to probabilites by exp(coef)/ (1-exp(coef) . But that gives you the probabilities of the coefs themselfs and not of the predictions. Can you specify what you are exactly looking for and what you have. Ie if you only have coefs how do you want to predict without data. If you have data, you could make a new model.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I do have the data but it’s a panel data and got me into some complexities when I was trying to use bootstrap technique to obtain the predicted probabilities. So, I had to run my bootstrap multinomial logit model in Stata to obtain bootstrapped coefficients first and  then to use R to obtain predicted probabilities. I posted my problem here but did not get any answer.

Comment: Here is the link for thread that I posted my original question but did not get any answer so I tried an alternative approach as described in the above question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410689/replicating-statas-bootstrap-command-for-panel-data-in-r-bootstrapping-in-r-in